# How to take text from a div that is hidden with a toggle button using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom-events

I need to take text from a div element using the `.text()` function, but the div is hidden using a toggle button and I can't take the text until the button is clicked once.

Is there a way to do this without having the button clicked? If not, can I use jQuery to double click it in milliseconds without the user actually seeing it? I've tried using the `.dblclick()` function, but it doesn't work.

Comment: do you have the ID or classname of the your target element? You can trigger a click on your target element. What's the ID or classname?

Comment: Is the target element the div that is hidden? And yes, I have the class but I can use it with .text() or .innerHTML() until the button is clicked and the div is opened at least once.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a class or id on the div and then use a selector and choose the value, like so:

```
<div id="myHiddenDiv" style="display:none">I have some TEXT.</div>
```

Next

```
var text = document.getElementById('myHiddenDiv').textContent;
alert(text);
```

Comment: When I try to console.log the text inside the div with your answer, it returns undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `div` has a identity name(selector name) If so then choose `selector` ID/Class, in the below example the `ID = mySelector`.

Ex.

```
<div id="mySelector">New content</div>
```

You just have to access the value of that selector. since you need that in your button click use below code.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("mySelector").innerHTML = "New content";
}
```

```html
<p id="mySelector">Old content</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

To fetch the value of the `mySelector` then use below code

```
var theValueYouNeed = document.getElementById("mySelector").innerHTML;
alert(theValueYouNeed);
Console.log(theValueYouNeed); //another option to view the value.
```

OR

```
var theValueYouNeed  = document.getElementById("mySelector");
alert(theValueYouNeed);
Console.log(theValueYouNeed); //another option to view the value.
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use trigger click of the button to toggle the div to make it hidden so you can get its text on init and each click. please check out below code snippet:

```js
var $div = $('#div1'); // hidden div
var $btn1 = $('#btn1'); // toggler button
var $showHere = $('#showHere');

$btn1.click(function() {
    $div.toggle();
    showDivText();
  })
  .trigger('click'); // trigger once on init

function showDivText() {
  $showHere.html($div.text());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">hello world</div>
<button id="btn1">Toggle Div</button>
<div>Text of div: <span id="showHere"></span></div>
```